# Custom built wordpress theme with underscore

Tags: php, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm trying to include a few custom fields I've created in my functions.php file so they're native to the theme I'm working on. However they're not showing up on the edit screens of the posts I've set them to.

I've included the acf plugin in my theme by using this code in my functions.php: include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');

I also exported the fields to php and copy and pasted the code in the functions.php of my theme. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Below is my exported code

```
define( 'ACF_LITE', true );
```

include_once('/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');

if( function_exists('register_field_group') ):

```
register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_about-us',
    'title' => 'About Us',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_586e22820cdf9',
            'label' => 'About Us',
            'name' => 'about_us',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Enter Title for about us here',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Title for about us here',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_586e22f80cdfa',
            'label' => 'Establised At',
            'name' => 'establised_at',
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'When where you established',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => '15',
                'order_no' => 0,
                'group_no' => 0,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'normal',
        'layout' => 'default',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
));
register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_food-menu',
    'title' => 'Food Menu',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58808cfded5b3',
            'label' => 'Price',
            'name' => 'price',
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_5881f02f46739',
            'label' => 'Currency',
            'name' => 'currency',
            'type' => 'select',
            'required' => 1,
            'choices' => array (
                '$' => '$',
                '&euro' => '€',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'allow_null' => 0,
            'multiple' => 0,
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_5880aceb6427c',
            'label' => 'Food Category',
            'name' => 'food_category',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'required' => 1,
            'choices' => array (
                'breakfast' => 'Breakfast',
                'lunch' => 'Lunch',
                'dinner' => 'Dinner',
                'party' => 'Party',
                'drinks' => 'Drinks',
            ),
            'default_value' => 'breakfast : Breakfast',
            'layout' => 'vertical',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'foodmenu',
                'order_no' => 0,
                'group_no' => 0,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'normal',
        'layout' => 'no_box',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
));
register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_footer-details',
    'title' => 'Footer details',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_5878f731da3ad',
            'label' => 'footer image',
            'name' => 'footer_image',
            'type' => 'image',
            'instructions' => 'Footer Image Goes Here',
            'save_format' => 'object',
            'preview_size' => 'medium',
            'library' => 'all',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_5878f756da3ae',
            'label' => 'footer content',
            'name' => 'footer_content',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'footer content goes here',
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58794f98697fa',
            'label' => 'Social Icons',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'tab',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58794d05697f8',
            'label' => 'Facebook Username',
            'name' => 'facebook_username',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Enter Your Facebook Username Here',
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'ajbeacon',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58794c93697f7',
            'label' => 'Twitter Username',
            'name' => 'twitter_username',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Enter Twitter Username Here',
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'ajbeacon',
            'prepend' => '@',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58794d65697f9',
            'label' => 'Google Plus Username',
            'name' => 'google_plus_username',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Enter Your Google Plus Username Here',
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '+ajbeacon',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => '15',
                'order_no' => 0,
                'group_no' => 0,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'normal',
        'layout' => 'default',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
));
register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_opening-time',
    'title' => 'Opening Time',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58795883ae60c',
            'label' => 'Opening Time',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'tab',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_587957a30aecf',
            'label' => 'Breakfast',
            'name' => 'breakfast',
            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'toolbar' => 'full',
            'media_upload' => 'yes',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_587957f00aed0',
            'label' => 'Lunch',
            'name' => 'lunch',
            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'toolbar' => 'full',
            'media_upload' => 'yes',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_587958310aed1',
            'label' => 'Dinner',
            'name' => 'dinner',
            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'toolbar' => 'full',
            'media_upload' => 'yes',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58795c760f586',
            'label' => 'Direction',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'tab',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58795c900f587',
            'label' => 'Address',
            'name' => 'address',
            'type' => 'text',
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Address Here',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58795d8550af4',
            'label' => 'Contact Details',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'tab',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58795da950af5',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => 'email',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter contact Email Address here',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'field_58795dde50af6',
            'label' => 'Phone Number',
            'name' => 'phone_number',
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Reachable Contact Phone Number Here.',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => '15',
                'order_no' => 0,
                'group_no' => 0,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'normal',
        'layout' => 'default',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
));
register_field_group(array (
    'id' => 'acf_signature-dishes',
    'title' => 'Signature Dishes',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_5878ff13d8ea4',
            'label' => 'Signature Dishes',
            'name' => 'signature_dishes',
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter Title Here Please',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'none',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => '15',
                'order_no' => 0,
                'group_no' => 0,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'normal',
        'layout' => 'no_box',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
));
```

endif;

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really tell what you're asking here.

Comment: @joe this is what i meant sorry about this miss information 

I'm trying to include a few custom fields I've created in my functions.php file so they're native to the theme I'm working on. However they're not showing up on the edit screens of the posts I've set them to.

I've included the acf plugin in my theme by using this code in my functions.php: include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your code that helped a lot.

the code is correct, the only possible error is with including the acf.php

if you have access to the FTP, put "advanced-custom-fields" folder next to the functions.php file. (in the same directory)

now in functions.php (the code you posted above) find this line:

```
include_once('/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');
```

replace it with this:

```
 include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');
```

let me know if that doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: thanks. I have done that and it does not work. it only works when i install custom fields

Comment: here is my file structure in my theme folder i have uploaded the image to dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9i46rl6wtnw5kdd/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-23%20at%2010.11.20.png?dl=0

Comment: it's working on my wordpress ...
anyways, do you get any errors ?

Comment: Okay did you activate the advanced custom fields plugin

Comment: no I moved it from the plugins folder to the theme folder

Comment: No errors I had to activate the plugin and hide it user-interface from users

Comment: Is it okay if I see how you reference the plugin in your theme folder

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/16e73ifcw6x099u/test.JPG?dl=0

I have new wordpress installed with blankslate theme

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fll2qmhbt19htab/functions.php?dl=0 
and this is the functions.php file that I use. 

I copied your code and just changed the include_once path

Comment: your advanced-custom-fields folder name is wrong. "s" in the end is missing